# How to view many succeeding pictures from a website?

Tags: web-browser, image-processing

Let's say, an website contains succeeding pictures, but there is no (online) album on that website, to find the pictures.
For example:
You know that
`www.site.com/kjhrr/rjekj/23323.jpg` and
`www.site.com/kjhrr/rjekj/23362.jpg` exist.
I could manually visit all URLs `.../23324.jpg` to `23361.jpg` to see if they exist, but that is very time consuming.
I'm *not* searching for a solution to try to *download* everything, like with httrack. I'd like to *view* (in an internet browser) all the pictures from `www.site.com/kjhrr/rjekj/23323.jpg` up to `www.site.com/kjhrr/rjekj/23362.jpg`. And then I could save only those pictures I want.

There could be a simple browser plug-in, which would recognize the URL `www.site.com/kjhrr/rjekj/23323...23362.jpg` or `www.site.com/kjhrr/rjekj/23323.jpg...23362.jpg`, and try do view them all (just ignoring the JPGs (URLs) which don't exist) but I couldn't find such a plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a tool that automatically does this, but it's relatively easy to write some JavaScript and execute that in the browser console (all major browsers have this, but you might need to enable the developer tools first). In your example, that would be

```
for (var i = 23323; i <= 23362; i++) {
  window.open("http://www.site.com/kjhrr/rjekj/" + i + ".jpg");
}
```

It does not filter out non-existing images; it's possible to write additional code which checks the URLs first but I fear that's outside the scope of this site.